# How does Angular or Typescript work?

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster

I don't know exactly how Angular or Typescript work, I think in this code , it should be 3 1 2. but it is 1 2 3. Please help me.

```
confirmDelete(id: number) {
    this.commentService.queryByStoryId(id).subscribe(
        (res: ResponseWrapper) => {
            this.comments = res.json;
            console.log(3);
        },
        (res: ResponseWrapper) => this.onError(res.json)
    );
    console.log(1);
    console.log(2);
    // for (let i = 0; i < this.comments.length; i++) {
    //     this.commentService.delete(this.comments[i].id);
    // }
    this.postService.delete(id).subscribe((response) => {
        this.eventManager.broadcast({
            name: 'postListModification',
            content: 'Deleted an post'
        });
        this.activeModal.dismiss(true);
    });
}
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIEat.png)   [Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEcs6.png)

Comment: javascript does not block

Comment: 3 1 2 is correct, because console.log(3) will be handled reactive. That means, that this observable need to be called. I your case, 
1,2 and then later on in eventManger.broadcast or somewhere the observer is calling. 
look here for more information about reactive programming
https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS

Comment: @DaveClough: It’s not that JavaScript doesn’t block; it’s that non-blocking things don’t block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in JavaScript (and TypeScript), the code is split in two categories :

- Synchronous code :

  The code executes itself synchronously because there is nothing to wait for, you tell him to do something and it does it.

  This is the case for this part of your code, which is executed as soon as you enter the `confirmDelete()` method :

*code part :*

```
 console.log(1);
 console.log(2);
```

- Asynchronous code :

  There is some code execution that is delayed because you need to wait for something before executing your own piece of code.

This is what happens in this part of the code :

*code part :*

```
this.commentService.queryByStoryId(id).subscribe(
  ...
);
```

You reach up to your Service Class `CommentService` and you need to execute the method `queryByStory()` synchronously. The thing is that since this method probably (from its look) execute an HTTP call to a backend service and what you want is execute some code after you receive the response.

What you see is the `subscribe()` method that comes from the library `RxJS` that allows you to catch the response from the HTTP call once the backend work has been done.

What it means is that everything in the `subscribe()` method is a new function executed asynchronously - when the response is ready.

So this code part is asynchronous and will execute after a delay :

```
    this.eventManager.broadcast({
        name: 'postListModification',
        content: 'Deleted an post'
    });
    this.activeModal.dismiss(true);
```

This is why you witness `1 2 3` and not `3 1 2`.

---

But then again you learn little by little, so before trying to code anything, learn what JavaScript is and you will learn the basics that you lack. You will then know what `Promises` are which are the basics about asynchronous code before trying to use other libraries such as `RxJS` and observables.

What I mean is that we cannot teach you this here, so it's up to you. And there is a lot on the Internet about that subject already.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and your advice. thank you.